# Possible to restore snapshot to existing VM Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I know it's possible to place a snapshot on a new VM and you'd be able to delete the old if you don't need it anymore, but I was wondering if it's possible to just restore the snapshot on the existing VM? All I can see are the options to create a new one for it.

Surely this isn't speedy at all, as I have to configure the VM again, have to choose a new name, and update all the project info again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snapshots can be used to create disks or VMs.  Snapshots are a photography of a particular state of the disk at a certain point of time.  As such it is not necessary to restore them on a particular VM.

If you want to preserve the existing IP address the VM is using, you can always:

1) [reserve the IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-instance-ip-addresses) 
2) [delete the original VM](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/delete) 
3)  [spin a new one](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) from the snapshot and re-assign the original IP.

Certainly this procedure take a couple of steps, but if you think doing it directly would be beneficial, you can submit a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/)